# TensorflowLite iOS example issue

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have downloaded the tensorflowlite Posenet example for iOS from the official GitHub account

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/posenet/ios

I am able to run the example on the device but it gives the following error

**2021-05-18 00:57:50.385071+0530 PoseNet[8112:3939417] Resizing Error: source image ratio and destination image ratio is different
2021-05-18 00:57:50.385531+0530 PoseNet[8112:3939417] Preprocessing failed
2021-05-18 00:57:50.385797+0530 PoseNet[8112:3939417] Cannot get inference result.**

Has anyone faced this issues and how do we solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is here.

1. Go to CVPixelBufferExtension.swift file.
2. Line 32: func resize(from source: CGRect, to size: CGSize) -> CVPixelBuffer?
   Please disable the following code.

   ```
   //    guard abs(rect.size.width / rect.size.height - source.size.width / source.size.height) < 1e-5
   //    else {
   //      os_log(
   //        "Resizing Error: source image ratio and destination image ratio is different",
   //        type: .error)
   //      return nil
   //    }
   ```

> Explanation: The resize function first checks if the current buffer `rect` contains the source `rect` with this code `guard rect.contains(source) else`. and the resize function actually crops the area of the frames from camera. so it doesn't need to validate the aspect ratio.
> That's why We can safely disable the code.

Comment: this works. But the library is behaving weird it does not work fast, I had used this around a year back and it was working properly, not sure what has changed now that the behaviour is also not as it was.